# SEPolicy for Android Native binder client

Tags: android, android-source, selinux, android-binder, seandroid

I'm new to the Android world

I want to know how to set  **SEPolicy for native binder client program** 
(And what to set as well..)

I'm using vendor binder (vndservicemanager) reference from [Using Binde-IPC](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#ipc)

And I add some files for the required SEPolicy

---

Now I have two built executables -- **my_binder_service** and **my_client**

both of them are under /vendor/bin/

**my_binder_service** is started at boot time, and it will add service to vendor servicemanager

**my_client** is a program that uses binder IPC to execute some function from **my_binder_service**

Here's my setting in **init.rc**

```
service my_binder_service /vendor/bin/my_binder_service
    class main
    class oneshot
    class console
    seclabel u:r:my_binder_service:s0
```

What's I have so far:

1. **my_binder_service** is successfully started at boot time
2. It can add service to vendor servicemanager
3. **my_client** behaves well under **permissive mode**

Things above are verified under enforcing mode, by **ps -AZ** and **vndservice list** command

---

### However, **my_client** runs into segmentation fault under **enforcing mode**

I check the denied message by

```
dmesg | grep avc | grep my_
logcat | grep avc: | grep my_
```

But I didn't find any message under both permissive and enforcing mode

I also check the contexts of these 2 running process by **ps -AZ** :

```
u:r:my_binder_service:s0  <- for my_binder_service
u:r:su:s0                 <- for my_client
```

I found that the process context is not set correctly for **my_client**

And I think this might be the issue of **my_client** under enforcing mode

I think **my_binder_service** is set correctly because of the **seclabel** command in init.rc file

But I don't know where to set the process context for my_client

Here's the content of my_client.te (my_binder_service.te is similar to this)

```
type my_client, domain;
type my_client_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

init_daemon_domain(my_client)

allow my_client my_client_exec:file entrypoint;
allow my_client serial_device:chr_file { read write };

vndbinder_use(my_client);
binder_call(my_client, my_binder_service);
```

and file context is specified in **file_context** file

```
/vendor/bin/my_binder_service      u:object_r:my_binder_service_exec:s0
/vendor/bin/my_client              u:object_r:my_client_exec:s0
```

Is anything missing in the SEPolicy part?

Or this isn't an issue about SEPolicy?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question few hours later..

It turned out that it's not related to the SEPolicy of client program

---

First, I found that **vndservice list** didn't lisy my_binder_service under **enforcing mode**, I mixed up with the result of **permissive** mode.

Then, I re-check the SOP in [Using Binder IPC](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#ipc) again to see if I missed anything.

And in fact! I did miss a lot of things...

---

Here's all the modification I made

```
# In vndservice_contexts 
my_binder_service                         u:object_r:my_binder_service:s0
```

I thought **seclabel** in **init.rc** works, but it turned out that this line is still necessary

```
# In my_binder_service.te
type my_binder_service, domain, vndservice_manager_type;
allow my_binder_service self:service_manager add;
```

vndservice_manager_type is added
and the allow rule is added based on **logcat| grep avc:** result and **audit2allow** 
command

The only change I made in **my_client.te** is that I delete **init_domain_daemon()** in it

Since I find it unreasonable after checking the te_macros file

---

And finally, everything works under **enforcing mode**

Except that the **process context** for **my_client** is still **su** instead of **my_client**, which I think might be irrelevant to this issue.

Maybe the only thing matters to the IPC between client and server is the following lines

```
binder_call(my_client, my_binder_service);
binder_call(my_binder_service, my_client);
```

Comment: Can you please help me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135573/add-vendor-service-to-servicemanager-with-android-treble-architectureselinux-po)