# Add vendor service to ServiceManager with android treble architecture[SELinux policy]

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, selinux, servicemanager

Note: I am beginner in SELinux policy and followed [vndservicemanager by Android](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#vndservicemanager)

I have a java service(MyService) that starts on the BootComplete receiver.
Now i am adding myservice to ServiceManager in onCreate of MyService.java.

```
ServiceManager.addService(mysystemservice, mybinder);
```

As per treble architecture,
I moved my application to vendor image partition by adding below in Android.mk of application.

```
LOCAL_VENDOR_MODULE := true
```

I made below changes in OEM SELinux policy, earlier it was written for system service now as i moved application to vendor so made changes for vendor service, providing both old and current SE policy.

> Created Context "my_service"

**OLD**

In *private/service_contexts*

`mysystemservice                         u:object_r:my_service:s0`

**NOW**

In *vendor/common/vndservice_contexts*

`mysystemservice                         u:object_r:my_service:s0`

> Defined Service Type

**OLD**

In *public/service.te*

`type my_service,            service_manager_type;`

**NOW**

In *vendor/common/vndservice.te*

`type my_service,  vndservice_manager_type;`

> Now giving add permission

**OLD**

In *public/servicemanager.te*

`allow system_app my_service:service_manager add;`

**NOW**

In *abc.te*

```
type abc, domain;
type abc_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(abc)

vndbinder_use(abc)

binder_call(abc, system_app)

add_service(abc, my_service)

allow abc  my_service:service_manager  find;
allow abc  my_service:service_manager  add;
```

After above changes and giving full build I can see my service context is part of out/product/target/vendor/etc/selinux/vndservice_contexts..inplace of out/product/target/system.

But once Myservice.java try to add "mysystemservice" in ServiceManager by

ServiceManager.addService(mysystemservice, mybinder);

I get below **avc denied ** error

**E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { add } for service=mysystemservice pid=7588 uid=1000 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2019-11-14 12:44:39.613 592-592/? E/ServiceManager: add_service('mysystemservice',b0) uid=1000 - PERMISSION DENIED**

As we can see in log above Target context is taking default "*tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0*" inplace of "*my_service*"

Note: If i keep changes for system image everything works fine only issue is when i move SE policy changes to vendor.

Please let me know if i missed something or any other way is to add Service.

Comment: Please check what `audit2allow` suggests as allow rule to be added: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#using_audit2allow

Comment: Hi, Tried but audit2allow is not helpful here, it is suggesting to add "default_android_service" in place of "my_service" below is the output from audit2allow:

#============= system_app ==============
allow system_app default_android_service:service_manager add;

Comment: Please check if the first row in your `vendor/common/vndservice_contexts` does contain the full path to the binary (e.g. `/vendor/bin/mysystemservice`).

Comment: Hi, Same issue is observed with suggested change..but one thing i observed, i don't see "mysystemservice" in "out/target/product/XYZ/vendor/bin" location. Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: The location depends on what you specified in your `Android.mk` or `Android.bp`. But yes, I would expect a default vendor binary to be located there. Where is your `mysystemservice`?

Comment: mysystemservice is in vendor/priv-app/

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that you are using `abc.te`, but you have not defined this in your `seapp_context` inside `vendor/common/`.

You should define something like below:

```
user=system
seinfo=platform
name=your.package.name
domain=adbc
type=system_app_data_file
```

After this change `avc` error will point to `abc` app domain.